# What is really going on when two natural magnets repel each other?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, magnetic-fields, photons, carrier-particles

I was listening to Frank Wilczek talking about how the electromagnetic force is actually a field, which is mediated by photons. What is our current/deepest understanding of what is happening when two natural magnets repel or attract each other?

Are they exchanging photons? Is the photon field "bending", similar to how the gravitational field bends? If photons are exchanged, can a detector see these photons?

Also what field of physics is the "real" theory of this kind of magnetism covered in? For instance, what textbook would I pick up to read about our current level of understanding of how magnets work, not the emergent explanation in electrodynamics?

Comment: Yeah sure I can elaborate. I mean "emergence" in the sense that macroscopic systems can be described in a way that doesn't consider the quantum effects. Like how we can describe the Earth's motion via its center of mass - we can describe electromagnetics with maxwell's equations (without regard to QFT).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been asking similar questions here for a while, relating to both electrostatic and magnetostatic fields. The short answer appears to be that there is a gap in the Standard Model. Quantum field theory postulates a zero-point magnetic field and simply plugs in Maxwell's classical equations to describe an actual magnetic field as a disturbance of that zero-point.

For electromagnetic radiation, an electron emits a real photon which carries away energy and momentum. But for magnetostatic and electrostatic fields which essentially just sit there exerting forces on things, there is only an appeal to the classical laws of Farady and co. (while quite possibly accompanied by a lecture that those same "forces" are classical things which do not exist at the quantum scale and are therefore a snare and a delusion!). Some people do talk of "virtual photons", but others say that makes no sense - without offering anything more quantised than the good Mr. Faraday.

Devices such as the superconducting quantum interference device (SQUID) are sensitive enough to pick up the stepwise changes in magnetic field strength as individual field quanta come and go, so it seems there is a quantum model to be had.

Experimentally there are no issues, but in terms of understanding there is just a big gap between those last two paragraphs.

Comment: You make a bold claim about SM not being able explain classical electromagnetism but without something substantial to back it up it is hard to comment on that. SM can absolutely obtain maxwell's equations for the fields in regimes where quantum corrections are small.  
As an avid user of this site you should know that "virtual particles" is just a name that refers to certain intermediate terms that appear in specific calculations.

Comment: @tbt One cannot prove a negative. What is needed is "something substantial" to explain how SM *does* describe a quantum of the magnetostatic field and how it exerts a force. I merely note an apparent absence of such explanation - I'd be extremely happy to have my ignorance exposed by "something substantial".

Comment: There are plenty of impossibility theorems around, so one can indeed prove a negative. Anyways, I'm sorry, I interpreted your answer as a statement on the theory.
A way of getting classical electromagnetism out of QFT is this. Let $S[A]$ be the classical action of the gauge field, and $\Gamma[A]$ the corresponding (renormalized) quantum effective action.  Considering the coupling of the field to an external current $J$,it is known that
$ \delta \Gamma[A] / \delta A_{\mu}  = J^{\mu} $ 
with A now being the quantum expectation value of the field (continues)

Comment: It also holds that $\Gamma[A]= S[A]+ \mathcal O(\hbar)$ , so, by using the above equation and the form of the classical action one gets $ \partial_{\nu} F^{\nu \mu}= J^{\mu} + \mathcal O(\hbar) $, which is telling us that the expectation value of the em gauge potential obeys the maxwell equations + quantum corrections (included in the terms of order $\hbar$ and higher)

Comment: So is the answer that "quantum effects do not contribute to electrostatic/macroscopic magnets"? How is there not photon exchange if photons are what mediate electromagnetic interactions?

Answer (score 2):

No, there are no photons being exchanged this way in such a case. What you are describing is photon exchange in the *quantum* electromagnetic force, which is not similar to how a large macroscopic magnet works. Instead, that is a purely quantum mechanical process that is described by the framework of quantum field theory. This can be explained in any introductory book on quantum field theory.

To understand the mechanism for such large magnets, and why they attract or repel each other, it is better to try to understand it from classical electromagnetic theory.

In this case, we imagine magnets to be composed of many tiny current loops made from electrons circling$^1$ in atoms. These loops are magnetic dipoles that each produce their own magnetic field.
The currents loops (magnetic moments) each add up to produce a total magnetic moment which results in the permanent magnet
(this is explained thoroughly in any text on classical electrodynamics).
The end result is the classical magnetic force you observe when magnets are brought close to each other.

$^1$ This is a simplification, and how electrons "circle" is more complicated, and in fact electrons form [probability clouds](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/81764/95176) in atoms.

Comment: Doesn't the standard model hold that photons are the force carriers for all EM field interactions, and therefore the magnets must be exchanging photons, since they are exerting forces on one another by the interaction of EM fields? Useless for explaining large scale effects, but nonetheless true?

Comment: Yes, but as stated above, this description holds only at a microscopic level. It would be incorrect to say that the same thing happens at a macroscopic level. Cheers and good luck with your studies.

Comment: What delimits a macroscopic system from a microscopic system?

Comment: @josephh But the macroscopic interaction is just the statistical aggregation of a gazillion quantum interactions. The same field equations (Maxwell's) underlie both QFT and classical EM. Anything in classical EM must therefore have a QFT origin.

Comment: "_Anything in classical EM must therefore have a QFT origin._" It's the other way around. Still, this does not change the fact that a macroscopic magnet is formed by a huge confluence of magnetic dipoles, and QFT describes what's happening microscopically, and **definitely** not the other way around. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

We have that electromagnetic field is thought of as acting as *mediator* of the electromagnetic interaction.

To that end the electromagnetic field is thought of as capable of carrying momentum.

In terms of any theory that describes interaction in terms of that interaction being mediated by a *field*:
Particles are not interacting directly with each other, they are all interacting with the *local* field.

In that way it is possible to account for the fact that when there is a change of the *source* of the field there is no immediate consequence for distant particles. The *change* propagates away from the source at a finite velocity.

Now let's take the case of an antenna that is used to broadcast a radio signal. The electromagnetic field around the antenna is changed continuously, and that change profile propagates away from the antenna.

As we know, electromagnetic waves are not dependent on the source, in the sense that once emitted electromagnetic waves continue to propagate after the source has stopped emitting.

**Photons**

Reception of electromagnetic energy can be set up in such a way that the energy is absorbed in discrete units. One example of a device that is designed to be triggered one discrete unit at a time is a [photomultiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photomultiplier)

Of course, in the case of electromagnetic waves these discrete units are referred to as 'photons'.

The thing is: a *measured* photon is a *vanished* photon. When a photomultiplier is triggered the unit of energy is *absorbed*.

Now we go back to the electromagetic field as *mediator* of electromagenetic interaction.

It is possible to describe the interaction in terms of interactions with virtual photons. It is referred to as a *virtual* photon because any photon that is measured is not available to act as mediator of electromagnetic *interaction*.

In my opinion it is a dodgy thing to say: "So-and-so is happening, but it is inherently impossible to measure it." If it is inherently outside the scope of measurement then it is better to *not include it* in the theory. In general, include in the theory only the things that are necessary in order to make the theory *work*.

In my opinion the concept of 'photons' becomes necessary when you get ever closer to definite *detection*, such as with a photomultiplier.

The context of the electromagnetic *interaction* is very field-like; nothing is definite yet.

So my recommendation is to not think in terms of interactions with virtual photons, and to concentrate on thinking in terms of interaction with a *field*.

Finally, you may be interested in the note titled [Magnetism, Radiation, and Relativity](https://physics.weber.edu/schroeder/mrr/MRRnotes.pdf) by Daniel Schroeder. Daniel Schroeder points out that it is possible to describe magnetism as a relativistic manifestation of the Coulomb force (the electrostatic force).

Comment: The OP is asking about magnetic fields. In general, a magnetostatic field does not carry away energy and momentum in the same way that a radiated electromagnetic field does, Can you explain the difference here?